USB autosuspend is enabled when TLP is automatically started on AC mode?
I'm using Debian 12 (bookworm) with KDE Plasma Wayland on a Thinkpad T470s (i5-7300u), and I've noticed that when I boot my laptop while plugged in, the USB autosuspend is enabled (while TLP seems to be started in AC mode). Running sudo tlp start fixes this, but it's still kinda annoying. What am I doing wrong?
Output of sudo tlp-stat:
    --- TLP 1.5.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings:
defaults.conf L0004: TLP_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0005: TLP_WARN_LEVEL="3"
defaults.conf L0006: TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT="0"
defaults.conf L0007: DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0008: DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT="2"
defaults.conf L0009: MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC="15"
defaults.conf L0010: MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT="60"
defaults.conf L0011: CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC="balance_performance"
defaults.conf L0012: CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT="balance_power"
defaults.conf L0013: SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0014: SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT="1"
defaults.conf L0015: NMI_WATCHDOG="0"
defaults.conf L0016: DISK_DEVICES="nvme0n1 sda"
defaults.conf L0017: DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
defaults.conf L0018: DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
defaults.conf L0019: DISK_APM_CLASS_DENYLIST="usb ieee1394"
defaults.conf L0020: DISK_IOSCHED="keep keep"
defaults.conf L0021: SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm max_performance"
defaults.conf L0022: SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="med_power_with_dipm min_power"
defaults.conf L0023: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC="on"
defaults.conf L0024: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0025: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT="15"
defaults.conf L0026: PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC="default"
defaults.conf L0027: PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT="default"
defaults.conf L0028: RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC="auto"
defaults.conf L0029: RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0030: RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC="default"
defaults.conf L0031: RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT="default"
defaults.conf L0032: WIFI_PWR_ON_AC="off"
defaults.conf L0033: WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT="on"
defaults.conf L0034: WOL_DISABLE="Y"
/etc/tlp.conf L0329: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC="0"
/etc/tlp.conf L0330: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT="10"
defaults.conf L0037: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER="Y"
defaults.conf L0038: BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0039: BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT="0"
defaults.conf L0040: BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
defaults.conf L0041: RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC="on"
defaults.conf L0042: RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0043: RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_DENYLIST="mei_me nouveau radeon"
defaults.conf L0044: USB_AUTOSUSPEND="1"
defaults.conf L0045: USB_EXCLUDE_AUDIO="1"
defaults.conf L0046: USB_EXCLUDE_BTUSB="0"
defaults.conf L0047: USB_EXCLUDE_PHONE="0"
defaults.conf L0048: USB_EXCLUDE_PRINTER="1"
defaults.conf L0049: USB_EXCLUDE_WWAN="0"
defaults.conf L0050: USB_AUTOSUSPEND_DISABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="0"
defaults.conf L0051: RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP="0"
defaults.conf L0052: RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT="0"
defaults.conf L0053: NATACPI_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0054: TPACPI_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0055: TPSMAPI_ENABLE="1"
/etc/tlp.conf L0169: PLATFORM_PROFILE_ON_AC="performance"
/etc/tlp.conf L0170: PLATFORM_PROFILE_ON_BAT="low-power"

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO ThinkPad T470s 20HF004VMX
BIOS           = N1WET74W (1.53 )
OS Release     = Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Kernel         = 6.1.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.85-1 (2024-04-11) x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = initrd=\bdd9ee8985a8447b936ff6cf8ef2a97e\6.1.0-20-amd64\initrd.img-6.1.0-20-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/t470s--vg-root ro quiet systemd.machine_id=bdd9ee8985a8447b936ff6cf8ef2a97e
Init system    = systemd v252 (252.22-1~deb12u1)
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
RDW state      = enabled
Last run       = 21:16:05,     53 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = AC

+++ Processor
CPU model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300U CPU @ 2.60GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  3500000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1..cpu3: omitted for clarity, use -v to show all

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status            = active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      =  11 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          =   0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/hwp_dynamic_boost =   0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct         =  29 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates       =  32

/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient       = N
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Platform Profile
/sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile                    = (not available)
/sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile_choices            = (not available)
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/dytc_lapmode       = (not available)

+++ Temperatures
/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal = 48 -128 0 0 0 0 0 0 [°C]
/proc/acpi/ibm/fan     =     0 [/min]

+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     0
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    20
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =    10

+++ Disks
Devices = nvme0n1 sda

/dev/nvme0n1:
  Type       = NVMe
  Disk ID    = nvme-SAMSUNG_MZVLW256HEHP-000L7_S35ENX0JB24286
  Model      = SAMSUNG MZVLW256HEHP-000L7              
  Firmware   = 5L7QCXB7
  Temp       = 36 °C
  Scheduler  = [none] mq-deadline (multi queue)

  Runtime PM:
    /sys/block/nvme0n1/device/power/control = on, autosuspend_delay_ms = (not available)

  SMART info:
    Critical Warning:                   0x00
    Temperature:                        36 Celsius
    Available Spare:                    100%
    Available Spare Threshold:          10%
    Percentage Used:                    3%
    Data Units Written:                 19,379,625 [9.92 TB]
    Power Cycles:                       1,877
    Power On Hours:                     2,084
    Unsafe Shutdowns:                   490
    Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0

/dev/sda:
  Type       = USB
  Disk ID    = usb-Generic-_SD_MMC_20120501030900000-0:0
  Model      = Generic SD MMC
  Firmware   = unknown
  APM Level  = none/disabled
  Status     = standby
  Scheduler  = [mq-deadline] none (multi queue)

  Runtime PM:
    /sys/block/sda/device/power/control = on, autosuspend_delay_ms = 15000

+++ Intel Graphics
/sys/class/drm/card0/device/driver           = i915

/sys/class/drm/card0/power/rc6_enable        =  1 (enabled)
/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_fbc_status      = FBC disabled: pixel format not supported
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_psr       = -1 (use per-chip default)

/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_min_freq_mhz         =   300 [MHz]
/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz         =  1100 [MHz]
/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_boost_freq_mhz       =  1100 [MHz]
/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_RPn_freq_mhz         =   300 [MHz] (GPU min)
/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_RP0_freq_mhz         =  1100 [MHz] (GPU max)

+++ Wireless
bluetooth = on
nfc       = none (no device)
wifi      = on
wwan      = none (no device)

hci0(btusb)                   : bluetooth, not connected
wlp58s0(iwlwifi)              : wifi, connected, power management = off

+++ Audio
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 0
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = N

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = [default] performance powersave powersupersave (using BIOS preferences)

+++ PCIe Runtime Power Management
Enable devices    = (disabled)
Disable devices   = (disabled)
Device denylist   = (disabled)
Driver denylist   = mei_me nouveau radeon

/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = on   (0x060000, Host bridge, skl_uncore)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = on   (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, i915)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.2/power/control = on   (0x118000, Signal processing controller, intel_pch_thermal)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control = auto (0x078000, Communication controller, mei_me)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.3/power/control = on   (0x070002, Serial controller, serial)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.2/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = on   (0x060100, ISA bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = on   (0x058000, Memory controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = on   (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.4/power/control = on   (0x0c0500, SMBus, i801_smbus)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.6/power/control = on   (0x020000, Ethernet controller, e1000e)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:3a:00.0/power/control = on   (0x028000, Network controller, iwlwifi)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:3c:00.0/power/control = on   (0x010802, Non-Volatile memory controller, nvme)

+++ USB
Autosuspend       = enabled
Device allowlist  = (not configured)
Device denylist   = (not configured)
Exclude audio     = enabled
Exclude bluetooth = disabled
Exclude phones    = disabled
Exclude printers  = enabled
Exclude WWAN      = disabled

Bus 002 Device 005 ID 2109:0813 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 004 ID 2109:0813 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 003 ID 17ef:1012 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- Lenovo Lenovo ThinkPad Dock (hub)
Bus 002 Device 002 ID 0bda:0316 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms = 2000 -- Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card Reader (usb-storage)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 009 ID 138a:0097 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms = 2000 -- Validity Sensors, Inc. (no driver)
Bus 001 Device 006 ID 8087:0a2b control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms = 2000 -- Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface (btusb)
Bus 001 Device 004 ID 058f:9540 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms = 2000 -- Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader (usbfs)
Bus 001 Device 010 ID 17ef:609c control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms = 2000 -- Lenovo Professional Wireless Keyboard (usbhid)
Bus 001 Device 011 ID 0424:2514 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB 2.0 Hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 007 ID 17ef:1011 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- Lenovo Lenovo ThinkPad Dock (hub)
Bus 001 Device 008 ID 2109:2813 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 005 ID 2109:2813 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 003 ID 17ef:1012 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- Lenovo Lenovo ThinkPad Dock (hub)
Bus 001 Device 002 ID 046d:c53f control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms = 2000 -- Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver (usbhid)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =    0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: thinkpad
Supported features: charge thresholds, recalibration
Driver usage:
* natacpi (thinkpad_acpi) = active (charge thresholds, recalibration)
Parameter value ranges:
* START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:  0(off)..96(default)..99
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:   1..100(default)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = LGC
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 00HW022
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =     76
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  24750 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  26250 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  25930 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Full

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_start_threshold =     96 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold   =    100 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_behaviour               = [auto] inhibit-charge force-discharge

Charge                                                      =   98.8 [%]
Capacity                                                    =  106.1 [%]

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT1 (Ultrabay / Slice / Replaceable)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = 01AV405
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    =     34
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design             =  22800 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full                    =  19400 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now                     =   8810 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Not charging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_start_threshold =     30 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold   =     80 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_behaviour               = [auto] inhibit-charge force-discharge

Charge                                                      =   45.4 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   85.1 [%]

+++ Charge total         

                               =   76.1 [%]

Output of sudo service tlp status:
● tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tlp.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2024-04-16 20:59:28 EEST; 26min ago
       Docs: https://linrunner.de/tlp
    Process: 1735 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/tlp init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1735 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 231ms

Apr 16 20:59:28 t470s systemd[1]: Starting tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown...
Apr 16 20:59:28 t470s tlp[1735]: Applying power save settings...done.
Apr 16 20:59:28 t470s tlp[1735]: Setting battery charge thresholds...done.
Apr 16 20:59:28 t470s systemd[1]: Finished tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown.

